# What kind of problems can be avoided if the post sound people are consulted during pre-prodution?

Tags: pre, production

What kind of problems can be avoided if the post sound people are consulted during pre-prodution?

Answer (score 1):

Budget, creative, and strategic problems most often in my experience.

I work with folks (both clients AND staff!) that often overlook sound as a part of the prepro/creative phase of a project.  We are in a constant state of involving ourselves when no one else does.  Projects turn out much better results when we are involved and have a head in the creative.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the film-maker and where their blind-spots are.

If they are a first time film maker they often have no idea what sound they are recording in the field, resulting in massive ADR time, or costly noise reduction hours. ie no one had headphones on while shooting...sighs...

Sometimes they edit the film with the camera sound in place when they recorded on a split system thinking it can be "button pressed" to make it "just work?" not realising that they should have used timecode equipment in the field or compiled their rushes before commencing the cut (!).
Ive seen both of those from inexperienced "film-makers" (using the term loosely).
There are ways around all those hurdles, like pluraleyes etc, but they take time and the results are never as good as a well crafted cut by a professional editor.

More creative issues come from cutting without thinking about the final audio - like cutting mid sentence to different POV's, cutting a car passing in one direction then to a different perspective where it's going in a different direction or just showing it receding into the distance expecting a big swoosh when their is no change in direction for it to move within the field of the mix.

The list of "if only we'd spoken about this before getting here" goes on and on for me...but that's because I'm largely cutting my teeth mixing low budget features. Hope that helps give some idea of the issues.

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks.  Wearing headphones  is a real obvious error.  Out of curiousity, what exactly is "low budget"?  I hear that term tossed around a lot and probably saw a pie chart for it on the web somewhere but I'm still unclear about how much money a low budget is.


Comment: The Editors Guild site proposes anything under $1.545 million is "Extremely Low Budget".

https://www.editorsguild.com/Wages.cfm

Comment: That depends on where you are and what your national economy is like, how many films get made and what finance they have. 

Comment: funny you mention cutting mid sentence cause that is what I am dealing with right now - looks like we're going to fix it in ADR - 

Comment: I think I like that number.

Comment: @Chris *VNB* I think you misunderstood Brent. He was saying that monitoring using headphones is imperative, not an error. It is important that you are aware of what the microphones are capturing, as they do not filter out unwanted sounds like we do.